# Django, get all required fields?

Tags: django

How can I get all the fields that is required for a model to be created?
(same as django migrations check before running migrations?)

Comment: You can use [`get_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) to iterate over all the fields and check which ones are required.

Comment: @solarissmoke: how do you check required? n

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`get_fields()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) method on the model `Meta` class:

```
fields = MyModel._meta.get_fields()
required_fields = []

# Required means `blank` is False
for f in fields:
    # Note - if the field doesn't have a `blank` attribute it is probably
    # a ManyToOne relation (reverse foreign key), which you probably want to ignore.
    if getattr(f, 'blank', False):
        required_fields.append(f)
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer above can be implemented slightly more concisely using list comprehension and `getattr()` with a default of `False`:

```
required_fields = [f for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if not getattr(f, 'blank', False) is True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more thorough way of getting a list of all required fields.

First, it gets all the fields from the model where blank=False. 
Second, it checks to see if you set required=False for any base fields in the form class. 
Third, it updates the list to give you all required fields.

One thing this function does not do is check whether you manually set required=True to any fields in the form class' **init** method.

```
def get_required_fields(form_class):
    """Get the required fields of a form. Returns a list of field names."""

    def get_blank_not_allowed_fields(model):
        """Get the list of field names where 'blank=False' for the given model."""
        blank_not_allowed_fields = []
        for field in model._meta.get_fields():
            if hasattr(field, 'blank') and field.blank is False:
                blank_not_allowed_fields.append(field.name)
        blank_not_allowed_fields.remove('id')
        return blank_not_allowed_fields

    blank_not_allowed_fields = get_blank_not_allowed_fields(form_class.Meta.model)

    # Even though, for certain fields, blanks are designated to be allowed (aka blank=True)
    # in the model class, they can have 'required' != True in the form class.
    # So, remove all fields where required is not True.
    for field_name, value in form_class.base_fields.items():
        if value.required is not True:
            blank_not_allowed_fields.remove(field_name)

    # At this point, if we are being precise, this variable should be named required_fields 
    # but, there is no point in changing the name of an already declared list.
    return blank_not_allowed_fields
```